# When a data set has an independent variable with two factors, when should I do a separate analyses?

Tags: categorical-data, model

I have a dataset where one independent variable indicates which person we are talking about. There are only two persons involved, so it's either person 1 or person 2.

When does one fit a model which takes data from both persons (where "Person" is a factor), and when does one fit a model for each person individually? What are the differences? What does the model "say" in each case?